# When testing Django REST Framework, why can't I get APIClient.credentials() to authenticate using a token?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, functional-testing, django-testing

I'm writing a functional (not unit) test against a basic API, like so:

```py
from decouple import config
from rest_framework.test import APIClient, APITestCase


class ObjectAPIResponseTest(APITestCase):
    base_url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/objects/'
    token = config('LOCAL_API_TOKEN') # token stored in local .env file
    authenticated_client = APIClient()

    def setUp(self):
        self.authenticated_client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + self.token)

    def test_list_object_reaches_api(self):
        real_response = self.authenticated_client.get(self.base_url)

        self.assertEqual(real_response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(real_response.headers['content-type'], 'application/json')
```

The test fails: `AssertionError: 401 != 200`

After successfully testing the request with curl, I decided to try to load up `requests` with the `Authorization` header instead of using Django REST Framework's `APIClient`:

```py
import requests

from decouple import config
from rest_framework.test import APIClient, APITestCase


class ObjectAPIResponseTest(APITestCase):
    base_url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/objects/'
    token = config('LOCAL_API_TOKEN') # token stored in local .env file

    authentication_header = {
        'Authorization': 'Token ' + token
    }

    def test_list_object_reaches_api(self):
        real_response = requests.get(self.base_url, headers=self.authentication_header)

        self.assertEqual(real_response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(real_response.headers['content-type'], 'application/json')
```

This passes, which makes me wonder if I'm somehow using `APIClient.credentials()` incorrectly, although what I've done seems basically in line with [the documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#apiclient).

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Inspired by Hafnernuss's comment, I wanted to see how the `APIClient` request was behaving, so I inspected the response from both the `APIClient` request and the `requests` request.

It looks like `APIClient` isn't actually hitting the API endpoint running on my development server, despite my explicitly requesting against its URL. If I remove the permission requiring a request to be authenticated and send a request through APIClient:

```py
client_response = self.authenticated_client.get(self.base_url)
print(client_response.data)
```

I get this as `response.data`:

```
[]
```

I know that there's at least one object in my local database accessible via that endpoint, though. If I create a new object in the context of the test and run the request, I get that object returned:

```
[OrderedDict([('id', 3), ('property', 'foo')])]
```

So I think I have a fundamental misunderstanding of what's going on under the hood with `APIClient`. Is it somehow mocking out the request to my local development server's URL and requesting from a contrived endpoint that pulls from the test runner's database?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but afaik the dbase would store the token you send with your request. If you load the token from the env, and this token is not stored in the db, how would the API know to which user the token belongs? I dont know why your second test passes, because you _should_ have the same issue there.

Comment: The token I'm using for authorization matches the token stored in the database for my local development server, which is how my local development server knows that the request is authorized. Your comment sparked an idea, though, to try to figure it out.

Comment: Regarding your update... Again, not sure, but how do you ensure that this entry really exists in your db? When testing, django sets up a dedicated test db that is cleared every time (this also means that tokens are not there!). In my tests, I insert my rows inside the setUp function of the testclass (i.E. accounts etc).

Comment: Yeah, as I'm learning more about the Django test runner, I see now that I did in fact have a fundamental misunderstanding of how `APIClient` and the internals of the test runner in general work. It's counterintuitive (at least for me) that the `APIClient` would behave this way even when hitting a live endpoint, but it makes sense in the broader context of the test isolation built into Django's test runner.

Comment: It has to be this way. If you are running your tests against a persistent db, your tests are not executed in a controlled environment anymore. This goes for everything inside Tests. Even `mymodel.objects.all()` won't return your rows while testing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution to bypass API authentication:

In fact, in order to disable any kind of API auth (Token, Basic, etc) simply you can use the following decorator on top of your `test_method()`:

```py
from unittest.mock import patch

from <Respetive-App>.<Respective-Views> import <Respective-View>

@patch.object(<Respective-View>, "permission_classes", [])
def test_post_rate(self, api_client):
    payload = dict(content_id=self.content.id, score=5)
    response = api_client.post(
        "/api/endpoint/",
        payload,
    )
    assert response.status_code == 201
```

Answer (score 0):

add the user's primary key to this

```
base_url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/objects/' + f'{user.pk}/'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).